# Getting LLVM error when building to device but not in simulator

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4, llvm-gcc, gh-unit

When I attempt to build my test target to either my iPad1 (4.3.5) or iPhone4 (4.3.5) I'm getting the following error from Xcode 4 (Build 4A304a):

```
Internal compiler error: tree check: expected tree that contains 'decl with visibility' structure, have 'const_decl' in c_common_truthvalue_conversion
```

But not when the Test Target is switched to build in the simulator.

The line of code that is borking is

```
GHAssertNotNULL(xxxObject, @"xxxObject could not be created");
```

(objects have been renamed to protect the innocent ;-) )  But I can say it is a singleton.

I've search google and didnt get anything relevant for this error.

Thanking you in advance
Ian.

Comment: Before someone suggests it I have already performed Product -> Clean.

Comment: As I cant answer my own question for another 6 hours, this is the answer I attempted to submit : -

Comment: I think I have answered the problem.

Initially it was a school-boy error on my behalf.  I shouldn't have been testing for null when the error condition returned would be nil.

Sounds easy-peasy so far.  I corrected the code and compiled again.  Same error but a much different scenario, performing a GreaterThan compare between an off_t value and zero (cast to off_t).

To cut a long story short I suspect the issue is 32 v 64-bit related (between the iPad and Simulator respectively).

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same compiler error:

```
internal compiler error: tree check: expected tree that contains 'decl with visibility' structure, have 'const_decl'  in c_common_truthvalue_conversion, at c-common.c:2836
```

Using Xcode 4.1 with GHUnitIOS-0.4.32 (and GHUnitIOS-0.4.31) when building for iOS devices. Note there is no issue when building for the simulator.

The complier errors involved calls to `GHAssertNotEqualObjects` and `GHAssertNotEquals`.

The code pattern that I was using when I received the compiler error was of the following:

```
- (void) test_isEqual {
    SomeObject *foo = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithValue: 1];
    SomeObject *bar = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithValue: 2];

    GHAssertNotEquals(bar, foo, @"Different Objects, different values - different pointers");
    GHAssertNotEqualObjects(bar, foo, @"Different Objects, different values - different pointers (calls isEqual)");
}
```

I was able to compile the code with the following modification:

```
- (void) test_isEqual {
    NSString *comment;
    SomeObject *foo = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithValue: 1];
    SomeObject *bar = [[SomeObject alloc] initWithValue: 2];

    comment = @"Different Objects, different values - different pointers";
    GHAssertNotEquals(bar, foo, comment);

    comment = @"Different Objects, different values - different pointers (calls isEqual)";
    GHAssertNotEqualObjects(bar, foo, comment);
}
```

Note that calls to `GHAssertEqualObjects`, `GHAssertEqualStrings`, `GHAssertEquals`, `GHAssertFalse`, `GHAssertNil`, `GHAssertNotNil`, and `GHAssertTrue` using a const NSString, i.e. @"some string", did not cause a compiler error.

Looking into `#define GHAssertNotEquals(a1, a2, description, ...)` and `#define GHAssertEqualObjects(a1, a2, description, ...)` and their use of `description`, both call `GHComposeString(description, ##__VA_ARGS__)`, but so do the others macros that work.

Comment: Thx! I had the same issue. I was able to get around it by using a slightly different custom assert macro. By passing the string constant pointer, rather than inlining it in the function call, I overcame the issue reliably.